# Gradle does not find tools.jar

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build

I am using javadoc doclets with gradle, so I need to use the package tools.jar, which is in the lib folder from the jdk (1.6.0_26 in my case).

The point is that gradle does not take it automatically, so I was adding that tools package to my libs folder, and then adding it to dependencies.gradle .

Now I want to take it directly from my JDK home into my dependencies.gradle. Is there a way to do that? I have tried the next in my dependencies.gradle:

```
compile files("${System.properties['java.home']}/lib/tools.jar")
```

But it does not find it while compiling.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that, as pre-cursor to solving this and as I ran into when I was getting this, you'll need to make sure you've actually got a JDK installed :P And, on some systems, you'll need to install the devel JDK package to get tools.jar

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Found it. **System property 'java.home' is not JAVA_HOME environment variable.** JAVA_HOME points to the JDK, while java.home points to the JRE. See [that page](http://javahowto.blogspot.de/2006/05/javahome-vs-javahome.html) for more info.

Soo... My problem was that my startpoint was the jre folder (C:\jdk1.6.0_26\jre) and not the jdk folder (C:\jdk1.6.0_26) as I thought(tools.jar is on the C:\jdk1.6.0_26\lib folder ). The compile line in dependencies.gradle should be:

```
compile files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar")
```

Comment: so, how to set java.home in idea with gradle ?

Comment: Any help for mac users?

Answer (score 163):

I had this problem when I was trying to run commands through CLI.

It was a problem with system looking at the JRE folder i.e. 
`D:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin`. If we look in there, there is no `Tools.jar`, hence the error.

You need to find where the `JDK` is, in my case: `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11`, and if you look in the `lib` directory, you will see `Tools.jar`.

What I did I created a new environment variable `JAVA_HOME`:
[image]

And then you need to edit your PATH variable to include JAVA_HOME, i.e.  `%JAVA_HOME%/bin;`
[image]

Re-open command prompt and should run.

Comment: the tool.jar is in `%JAVA_HOME%\lib;` not in `bin` folder.

Comment: does this mean that we should be adding both `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` and `%JAVA_HOME%/lib` to the `Path` variable then?

Comment: Even though tools.jar is indeed in \lib, adding only \bin to path as in solution worked for me but don't ask why.

Comment: Usually a restart/logout is required for changes to have an effect.

Comment: I had to remove the PATH entry C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath and replace it with C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\jdk1.8.xxx it was defaulting to the sister JRE directory

Answer (score 74):

I got the same error using Eclipse trying to execute a Gradle Task. Every time I run a command (i.e. war) the process threw an exception like:

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\Jre8" is a valid JDK install.

I tried the solution listed in this post but none of them solved this issue. Here my solution :

1. Go to the "Gradle Task" view
2. Right Click on the task you want to execute
3. Select Open Gradle Run Configuration
4. In the tab "Java Home" select your local JDK repository then click OK

Run again, Enjoy!

Comment: I've found this answer after hours of searching, and this finally worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: I cant find Open Gradle Run and Java Home. Can you explain further?

Comment: Being new to this, how would one "Go to the "Gradle Task" view"? I don't see anything Gradle under the View menu, nor anything labeled anything like that?

Answer (score 62):

I just added a `gradle.properties` file with the following content:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_45
```

Comment: On linux, you can also edit `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, adding `org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java`. Works for me on Fedora 24.

Answer (score 44):

I had a similar case using **Ubuntu**. The machine had only the **JRE** installed. So, I just executed the command below to install the **JDK**.

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: Yes, installing JDK instead of JRE also solved the problem for me.

Comment: I was getting the same issue even though i had java installed and i saw a folder for openjdk. Later only i realized that the folder had only JRE installed. Not JDK.

Comment: So I had the jdk installed, my JAVA_HOME set -- I ran this exact command and verified with `java -version` (Debian). Then after seeing this comment, for kicks I re-ran it, and then my build worked fine. I'm not sure what happened, it must have missed some packages on the initial install. Thank you though!

Answer (score 38):

**In macOS Big Sur**

The issue happens because of the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not correctly set in macOS Big Sur.

Step 1 - Confirm that you have issue with `JAVA_HOME` by printing its value in the terminal. You will most likely get an empty string.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Step 2 - Find the correct path on your machine

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Copy that path associated with "Java SE 8" which usually looks like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home`

Step 3 - Edit `.zshenv` using `nano`

```
nano ~/.zshenv
```

Step 4 - Add the path from step 2 to the file as follows

```
export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JAVA_PATH
```

example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Step 5 - Source the updated `.zshenv` file to activate the environment variable

```
source ~/.zshenv
```

Step 6 - Print to confirm the path

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: These 6 steps WORKED! after 3 days of nada -> r3 Corda docs & various tutorials say to modify `~/.zshrc` which does not work on my Mac.

Answer (score 27):

I was struggling as well for this Solution. Found a better way to it with Gradle as described [here](http://mohammed-technical.blogspot.com/2016/03/getting-jdk-information-in-gradle-to.html?soo).
We can get the JVM/JDK information from Gradle itself.

```
dependencies {
   runtime files(org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().toolsJar)
}
```

So simple.

Comment: This works for me if I use `compile` instead of `runtime`

Comment: I like this solution.  It's nice and portable.

Comment: This solution  does not work with Gradle 4.x. I get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I can imagine it returning null when there is no tools.jar available with latest JDK. See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/base-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/jvm/Jvm.java#L297

Answer (score 22):

In CentOS7 the development package will install tools.jar. The file is not present in java-1.8.0-openjdk

`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Comment: Thanks Richard! It really helped me! I was struggling running "react-native run-android" and getting the error: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-5.b14.fc27.x86_64/jre contains a valid JDK installation. Now it's working! Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Richard..It worked for me as well. Basically it was a JAVA_HOME path issue which tried to find tools.jar in the desired java jdk path.

Comment: I am using Amazon Linux AMI and this solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 19):

Add this to `gradle.properties`:

> org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Comment: Don't forget to use double back slashes. For example: `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144\ `.

Answer (score 13):

My solution on Mac:

add this line to `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
```

not this one:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

you can open the last home directory and will find that there is no `lib/tools.jar` file existence, so change the path to `JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk` and it works for me.

By the way, in the terminal, I echo the `$JAVA_HOME` and it gets the first path, not the second one, I think this is why my Gradle cannot work properly.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the $JAVA_HOME environment to my `.zshrc` and adding it to `gradle.properties` did it for me :D

Answer (score 12):

With Centos 7, I have found that **only JDK has `tools.jar`, while JRE has not**. I have installed the Java 8 JRE(`yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`), but not the JDK(`yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`).

Installing the latter solves the problem. Also, remember to set `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 11):

It may be two years too late, but I ran into the same problem recently and this is the solution I ended up with after finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626757/correct-way-of-referencing-tools-jar-in-a-cross-platform-way/25628156#25628156):

```
import javax.tools.ToolProvider

dependencies {
  compile (
    files(((URLClassLoader) ToolProvider.getSystemToolClassLoader()).getURLs()),
    ...
  }
}
```

It should work if java.home points to a directory that's not under the JDK directory and even on Mac OS where you'd have classes.jar instead of tools.jar.

Comment: Cannot invoke method getURLs() on null object

Answer (score 10):

On windows 10, I encounter the same problem and this how I fixed the issue;

1. Access `Advance System Settings>Environment Variables>System
   Variables`
2. Select **PATH** overwrite the default
       `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
3. With your own jdk installation that is **JAVA_HOME**=`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for Windows :)  --thanks

Answer (score 9):

On my system (Win 10, JRE 1.8.0, Android Studio 3.1.2, Gradle 4.1) there is no `tools.jar` in the JRE directory (`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171`).

However, I found it in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\lib` and tried setting **`JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`**

That works (for me)!

Comment: Same issue, fixed it for me, also Win 10/Android Studio.   Also, none of the above solutions actually seems to download a "Tools.jar" ... just doesn't come with the jre)

Comment: Worked for me too. I created a gradle.properties in the project root containing `org.gradle.java.home=E:\\Android Studio\\jre`

Answer (score 5):

What solved it for me was the following:

1. found tools.jar in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\lib
2. copy paste to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib
3. ran the code again and it worked.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the answer :)
I am sure that worked.... However, please check the other answers in this question. It will help you in the future to understand the differences between the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) and the Java Development Kit (JDK).

Comment: It works for me!! So this comment helps me to solve my problem as well. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 4):

If you use terminal to build and you have this error you can point to jdk bundled with android studio in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/local/android-studio/jre
```

Answer (score 3):

**Linux**

Open `/etc/environment` in any text editor like *nano* or *gedit* and add the following line:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk"
```

**Windows**

1. Start the System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control
   Panel - System).
2. Select the Advanced tab.
3. Click the Environment
   Variables button.
4. Under System Variables, click add button, then past the following lines:

   in Variable Name : `JAVA_HOME`

   in Variable Value :  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_xxx`

   where `x.x_xxx` jdk version you can get your jdk version from here `C:\Program Files\Java`
5. Under System Variables, select Path, then click Edit,then click new button then past the following line:

   `%JAVA_HOME%/bin;`

Comment: Paths may vary slightly. In Fedora this worked for me with `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk"`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

I was getting message

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121 contains a valid JDK installation.

- In Android Studio, check your SDK Location.
- File, Project Structure, SDK Location, JDK Location.
- Example: C:\android-studio\android-studio\jre
- Copy the tools.jar file in the C:\android-studio\android-studio\jre\lib folder into the C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib folder.
- Retry.

Answer (score 2):

Like other answers I set **org.gradle.java.home** property in **gradle.properties** file. But path with \ separators did not work (building on windows 10):

> Java home supplied via 'org.gradle.java.home' is invalid. Invalid
>   directory: C:Program FilesJavajdk1.8.0_65

So instead of

> org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

i had to use

> org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_65

then the build was successful

Problem is that project is build with JRE instead of JDK and since I was building it from eclipse this also worked:

- In Window>Preferences>Gradle>Arguments specify Workspace JRE and specify your JDK.
- In Window>Preferences>Java>InstalledJREs specify your JDK as default

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Windows 10) after Java update I lost my Enviroment Variables, so I fixed added the variables again, based in the following steps https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem on this way:

- download file tools-1.8.0.jar on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtools180jar.htm
- unzip file and rename to tools.jar
- copy to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib folder
- Retry

Comment: Had to copy it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251`

Answer (score 2):

Put in gradle.properties file the following code line:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_45
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LmtZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use this with modern versions of gradle:

```
def compiler = javaToolchains.compilerFor { languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(java.sourceCompatibility.majorVersion) }.get()
implementation compiler.metadata.installationPath.files('lib/tools.jar')
```

Comment: the most elegant answer inspired as I understand by official Gradle documentation (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html)

Comment: now amended so that the language version need not be hard-coded

Comment: NB. this is not used for Java 17 - there is no tools.jar any more..

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that tools.jar made it on the compile class path? Maybe the path is incorrect.

```
task debug << {
    configurations.compile.each { println it }
}
```

Comment: Yes it did made it to class path, but still getting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding JDK path through JAVA_HOME tab in "Open Gradle Run Configuration" will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried most of the top options but it seems that I had something wrong with my environment setup so they didn't help. What solved the issue for me was to **re-install** `jdk1.8.0_201` and `jre1.8.0_201` and this solved the error for me. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Years later: With Arch Linux I still had java-8-openjdk set as the default. Simply setting a newer version as the default solved the issue for me: `sudo archlinux-java set java-20-openjdk`. I added this as a comment to your solution since I believe it is very similar to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Could not find tools.jar**

MacOS

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And restart Shell

Answer (score 0):

For me this error ocurred after trying to use audioplayers flutter library.
To solve i got tools.jar of the folder:

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\lib

and pasted on

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib.

After this the build worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

**My Android Studio Version: 4.2.1**

The **"tools.jar"** is provided by Oracle JDK which is required by android studio for compilation - I have faced this issue after updating android studio to latest version in my PC.

**To Resolve the issue follow below steps:**

1. In Android studio File -> Project Structure -> SDKs (Under Platform Settings)

   A) Add JDK path by pressing '+' symbol in middle pane if suppose JDK/JDK home path is not present in the middle pane already (Middle pane also contains the Downloaded Android SDK's)

   B) Java sdk will be usually present/installed in the path 64 bit => "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.X.Y_ABC" (In my PC it is 1.8.0_202) or 32 bit => "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.X.Y_ABC"
2. If suppose you don't have JDK installed in your PC,
   please download and install from Oracle Java website
   https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

3. Set JDK and JRE Path(Download both from webpage mentioned in step 2) in system environment variable

   A) Press windows key type "Edit the system environment variables" and open the application

   B) Go to Advanced -> Environment Variables Under system variables add JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME as below

[Set Windows system environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUUlc.png)

4. Add jdk lib path on the Path environment variable under user variables (this step is required only if the error not resolves with the previous steps)
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.X.Y_ABC\lib

Answer (score 0):

For Windows add JDK home path to the Gradle property file as org.gradle.java.home.
If you don't have gradle.properties file then create a new one and add

Ex: org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241

Answer (score 0):

In Case, Non of the above solutions work. Simply copy tools.jar file from jdk folder into the jre folder. Make sure you have elevated privileges before you make this move.