# Gradle Build failed with an exception following spring tutorial

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to gradle so i was following the following tutorial : https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/#scratch

when i run the gradle task i can see that the java tasks are showing after creating a build.gradle with apply plugin: 'java'
But when i use the command gradle build i get following error.

FAILURE: Gradle Build failed with an exception 
*what whent wrong:
execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
could not find tools.jar
*try..

any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345193/gradle-does-not-find-tools-jar). Seems similar to your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
if you have more than one JRE installed in your machine, copy the tools.jar to more recent JRE1_x.x_xx version under lib directory.
My gradle crashed when I update to more recent gradle and more recent java runtime, and I don't know why java leave the older JRE version folder.

Comment: I don't think this is good advice; the copying jars from one JRE to another seems like a recipe for disaster