# android - Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

New to Android Studio + Gradle.

I'm trying to run my app from the command line using:

```
gradlew installDebug
```

The app gets installed on my device only when I execute that command when Studio just got opened and do that initial syncing/building thing.

Whenever I modified my code, and try to run that command again, the build fails and shows this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
> Could not find tools.jar
```

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle file

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Setting the JAVA_HOME variable to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdkX.XX** worked for me.

It was previously set to the JRE directory for some reason.

Comment: this is the correct fix. Detailed how-to on Windows 10: **1)** go to Search bar and type in "environment" and click on "Edit the system environment variables". **2)** click on "Environment Variables" button **3)** under System Variables heading, click "new". Enter the name as JAVA_HOME and look up the path to the jdk like Jeffrey said. Click OK and OK again. **4)** close your DOS window and open a new one. Now gradlew will work fine

Comment: Note: in windows you check the variable by typing in `echo %JAVA_HOME%` on a DOS window. It should show you the C:\Program Files\Java\... path. If it doesn't, then you didn't successfully create the variable, or you didn't exit the DOS window after you created the system variable.

Comment: For me what worked was adding the correct %`JAVA_HOME`% + `/lib` to the `PATH` variable. From[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35623142/1219280)

Answer (score 8):

Are you on Linux? What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` outputs?

I had a similar issue when running `react-native run-android`. After setting $JAVA_HOME (which hadn't existed) to a JDK folder, the problem was solved. In my case, I added the following line to the end of *.bashrc* file:

```
export JAVA_HOME="path/to/a/folder/with/JDK/jdk1.8.0_60"
```

and restarted the terminal.

Comment: I'm not OP but I have a similar error (same task, different error) and I'm on Ubuntu. I didn't had `JAVA_HOME` so I added it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` and same error.

Comment: I just "fixed" the problem, my react-native project was called `native` and you can't do that: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3437#issuecomment-152888456

Comment: Restarting terminal is also an important part +1

Comment: NOTE: this is stupid but make sure you have the JDK actually installed (not just the JRE) in Ubuntu you run: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`. It will give you the same error.

Answer (score 6):

I deleted `.gradle` file from project root directory and rebuilt the app and then everything was working fine.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone facing this issue after updating to AndroidStudio-2.0

I previously had AndroidStudio-1.3 and jdk-1.7.X_XX. When I updated to AndroidStudio-2.0, things worked fine until I rebooted the computer. After reboot, I encountered this error and none of the above answers worked for me.
Here's what I did:

1. Copied the project into a new folder
2. Upgraded my jdk version from 1.7.X_XX to 1.8.X_XX
3. Changed the JDK's path in the project structure to the new path:

   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.X_XX
4. Gradle sync

And things worked.

Answer (score 2):

ALL above answers are correct. I just wanna mention that if you are using MAC, and the full path of JDK path should be

```
"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Do not miss /Contents/Home

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers did not work for me. This is what worked:
(Ubuntu, but should work for others as well)

1. Go to your project folder:`/.../projectlocation`
2. Then to android folder: `/.../projectlocation/android`
3. Find `gradle.properties` file and add this line anywhere in the file: `org.gradle.java.home=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_91`

Notice that there are no quotes and the right side of the example is my JDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.I was looking for several hours on stack overflow and tried all of the way they said but was not able to solve the problem.Then I found that problem was in my ***project folder name***.I just **rename** the folder name and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/"

i'am using zshrc i added up line.
after that carefully 
echo $JAVA_HOME in terminal
You should see /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home after that build will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in Android Studio

-> after 7 hours i found SOLUTION of this issue in my project level "build.gradle" file.

-> Simple to Remove only 2 things from your "build.gradle" file.

```
        buildscript { 
          maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
        
        allprojects{
            mavenCentral{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
```

-> and update the version of gradle just like.

```
        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        }
```

-> done.