# Error building/running Android app: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javac

My app was working perfect until I implemented Dagger to my project and some other minor classes to make my app interact with external server.

Now i cant do anything. Im working on Android Studio 2.0, Ubuntu 15.04. I have no idea of what is causing the problen, so feel free to ask for whatever you want to see.

This is what I get from Gradle console:

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_77). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Messages:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055209/android-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac

Comment: Already tried setting JAVA_HOME: echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle. Where is this variable used?