# Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH environment variable has been written

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am experiencing the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   annot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

I have set the `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` environment variables. Please help!

Comment: there is a solution [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055209/android-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac) I hope this help you.

Comment: what you take in path in environment variable?

Comment: the environment variable:
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
javac at working.