# Gradle cannot find tools.jar

Tags: eclipse, gradle, tools.jar

As it's mentionned in the title, when I want to run my task for gradleit gives me an execution failed for task ':compileJava'. could not find tools.jar
I checked for tools.jar in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\lib and I found it, I added JRE (windows -> preferences -> java -> Add JRE and apply it). But the probelm stills the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345193/gradle-does-not-find-tools-jar

Comment: Thank you Brian, I already checked this  post but I still have the issue with compileJava,
Execution failed for task :compileJava.
I added Jdk to my System variable (new variable and path too) and I added compile files("${System.properties['java.home']}/../lib/tools.jar") to my gradle.build but the problem stills the same.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message with the eclipse gradle plugin, and needed to set my JDK in the gradle arguments.

[image]