# Could not find tools.jar when build gradle project

Tags: java, windows, gradle

I try build gradle project and get error:

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144 contains a valid JDK installation.

I add to `path`

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin
```

when I write java and javac in console all works. But project not build

Comment: Check this and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345708/6266949

Comment: check your env variables JDK != JRE - see your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457282/gradle-not-found-java-class-path/45459678#45459678)

Answer (score 8):

The reason it works in your console is because your console is most likely picking up its JDK from your JAVA_HOME value in your environment settings.

For Gradle, you need to create a **gradle.properties** file in your application's root directory (if it does not already exist) and add the following line:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/path/to/your/jdk
```

When you copy your path from the Windows Explorer, please remember to change "\" to "/", otherwise, they will be escaped and you will receive an error inside of Eclipse.