# Gradle not found java class path

Tags: java, windows, gradle, classpath

I set `JAVA_HOME` path - `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112`

and add to the path next links - `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `%JAVA_HOME%\lib`

but when I try to build Gradle project I get the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find tools.jar.
>   Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144 contains a valid
>   JDK installation.

But I do not understand how Gradle found `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144` I have not this in my class path

How can I set the correct path for Gradle?

Comment: What do you see if you write `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in the cmd before running the gradle build?

Comment: How are you running the build?

Comment: @ BackSlash C:\Users\Pavel>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

Comment: All earned. Reloaded the console