# Build is getting in goCd pipeline for gradle project

Tags: java, go-cd

I am new to goCd. I have go server and agent in my local system.Created a pipeline for build but its getting fail with below error.

> [go] Task: gradlew buildtook: 2.162sexited: 1
>       :compileJava FAILED
>       1 actionable task: 1 executed
>
> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Go Agent\jre contains a valid JDK installation.
>
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
> [go] Task status: failed, took: 2.162s, exited: 1
> ```
>
> [go] Current job status: failed

I have seen similar kind of issue for maven project where go agent is not able to find the JDK path but how to do setup JDK for go agent is not clear.Please let me know for more information.

Comment: Have a look at this, seems similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345193/gradle-does-not-find-tools-jar

Comment: @rocky did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Return_Of_The_Archons No so I changed the build tool to gradle and It was working fine.