# Gradle can't find tools.jar

Tags: java, gradle, build, java-8, opensuse

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11345193/4457885) but the answer did not solve my problem. The answers only address windows systems and provide file paths which are not helpful for the OS I am running.
I am running openSUSE Leap 15 with Java 1.8, changing the OS or Java version is not an option.

When I try to build with the command `./gradlew clean build` i get the following error:

```
:buildtools:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildtools:compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.364 secs
```

I have checked my Java installation like this:

```
 $> rpm -qa | grep java
javapackages-tools-5.0.0+git20180104.9367c8f6-lp150.1.2.x86_64
timezone-java-2018g-lp150.2.13.1.noarch
java-1_8_0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-lp150.2.6.1.x86_64
libjavascriptcoregtk-4_0-18-2.20.5-lp150.2.6.1.x86_64
java-1_8_0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.181-lp150.2.6.1.x86_64
```

I also checked out JAVA_HOME:

```
$> echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Comment: What does your gradle file look like, it says you're referencing to the `jre` while you should be referencing to the `jdk` to use `tools.jar`.

Comment: Gradle requires a JDK (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html#sec:prerequisites ) : your $JAVA_HOME is pointing on a JRE installation, which does not contain the needed `tools.jar`. Can you reconfigure JAVA_HOME to point on your JDK instead of JRE ?

Answer (score 3):

The comments inspired me to find a solution. Apparently installing the package [java-1_8_0-openjdk](https://software.opensuse.org/package/java-1_8_0-openjdk) will only provide the OpenJDK 8 runtime environment. I wrongly expected it to include the development tools because of the 'jdk' in its name (**J**ava **D**evelopment **K**it).

My problem was solved by simply installing the package [java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel](https://software.opensuse.org/package/java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel) which actually includes the development tools, like this: `sudo zypper in java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel`.

The command `zypper se jdk` can help you to figure out the status of your jdk installation. After installing the package java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel you should see an `i+` next to the package name. You should be able to spot the following two lines:

```
i+ | java-1_8_0-openjdk        | OpenJDK 8 Runtime Environment      | package
i+ | java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel  | OpenJDK 8 Development Environment  | package
```