# Gradle does not create library (minecraft forge mdk)

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I downloaded forge-1.15.1-30.0.41-mdk, extracted the file into my mod folder and imported  it into eclipse as  an "existing gradle project".

Now my problem: Gradle did not create a library with the net.minecraft.* and net.minecraftforge.* packages. So I can not import anything to my code.

The output on the console when I tried to Import:

```
`https://pastebin.com/7ushke8k`
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url = 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven' }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '3.+', changing: true
}
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
// Only edit below this line, the above code adds and enables the necessary things for Forge to be setup.
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = '1.0'
group = 'com.yourname.modid' // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = 'modid'

sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = compileJava.sourceCompatibility = compileJava.targetCompatibility = '1.8' // Need this here so eclipse task generates correctly.

minecraft {
// The mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
// snapshot_YYYYMMDD   Snapshot are built nightly.
// stable_#            Stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
// Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not always work.
// Simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20190719-1.14.3'
// makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.

// accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

// Default run configurations.
// These can be tweaked, removed, or duplicated as needed.
runs {
    client {
        workingDirectory project.file('run')

        // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
        property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

        // Recommended logging level for the console
        property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

        mods {
            examplemod {
                source sourceSets.main
            }
        }
    }

    server {
        workingDirectory project.file('run')

        // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
        property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

        // Recommended logging level for the console
        property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

        mods {
            examplemod {
                source sourceSets.main
            }
        }
    }

    data {
        workingDirectory project.file('run')

        // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
        property 'forge.logging.markers', 'SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP'

        // Recommended logging level for the console
        property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

        args '--mod', 'examplemod', '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/')

        mods {
            examplemod {
                source sourceSets.main
            }
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
// Specify the version of Minecraft to use, If this is any group other then 'net.minecraft' it is assumed
// that the dep is a ForgeGradle 'patcher' dependency. And it's patches will be applied.
// The userdev artifact is a special name and will get all sorts of transformations applied to it.
minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.15.1-30.0.41'

// You may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs or you may define them like so..
// compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
// compile "some.group:artifact:version"

// Real examples
// compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
// compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

// The 'provided' configuration is for optional dependencies that exist at compile-time but might not at runtime.
// provided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

// These dependencies get remapped to your current MCP mappings
// deobf 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

// For more info...
// http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
// http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

// Example for how to get properties into the manifest for reading by the runtime..
jar {
manifest {
    attributes([
        "Specification-Title": "examplemod",
        "Specification-Vendor": "examplemodsareus",
        "Specification-Version": "1", // We are version 1 of ourselves
        "Implementation-Title": project.name,
        "Implementation-Version": "${version}",
        "Implementation-Vendor" :"examplemodsareus",
        "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    ])
}
}

// Example configuration to allow publishing using the maven-publish task
// we define a custom artifact that is sourced from the reobfJar output task
// and then declare that to be published
// Note you'll need to add a repository here
def reobfFile = file("$buildDir/reobfJar/output.jar")
def reobfArtifact = artifacts.add('default', reobfFile) {
type 'jar'
builtBy 'reobfJar'
}
publishing {
publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        artifact reobfArtifact
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "file:///${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: add more information. `build.gradle` file etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
You have to declare the Java Home manually at importing the project.
There I saw it:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345193/gradle-does-not-find-tools-jar)