# Running React Native Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have followed all the steps from here:http://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

but I am getting this error:
[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your **JAVA_HOME** environment points to (C:\jdk1.6.0_26\lib) folder and not (C:\jdk1.6.0_26\jre). Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345193/gradle-does-not-find-tools-jar)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set SDK dir in android/local.properties (if not create that file)

```
## This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Fri Sep 06 20:07:53 BST 2019

sdk.dir=/Users/<youcomputername>/Library/Android/sdk
```