# React native running issue

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, avd-manager

I am stuck with to run my app. When i run `yarn android` i get below error:

[image]

[image]

What i tried is:

- Cold boot from AVD manager
- cd app and ./gradlew clean
- cd app and ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
- uninstall node_modules then reinstall it again

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Please read the error message, your problem in tools.jar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345193/gradle-does-not-find-tools-jar